# Unable to install types for Framer motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have tried running the command `npm install @types/framer-motion` and also `npm install @types/framer` but both of them give a 404. How to install the types for framer motion.

I asked bing chat which asked me to run npm install `@types/framer-motion` but it gives 404. No entry in the registry.

Comment: framer-motion is written in typescript. You don't need to install types for it. In fact framer doesn't have any different package for installing types. (Hint: Open npm and find framer-motion. Look at the title, you will see TS written there. This means that it's written in typescript and doesn't need extra types installation. If it were DT, the case would be different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`framer-motion` comes with types by default. you don't need to install type for it.

You can check it under node_modules/framer-motion
[image: Folder struct]

Here is an example in how to use it:

```js
import { motion, Variants } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

const variants: Variants = {
    main: {
        left: 0,
    },
    left: {
        left: -500,
    },
};

interface Props {
    mode: "open" | "close";
}

const Test: React.FC<Props> = ({ mode }) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <motion.div
                animate={mode === "open" ? "main" : "left"}
                variants={variants}
                transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
                style={{
                    top: 30,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    position: "absolute",
                }}
            ></motion.div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

With `const variants: Variants` you now will have auto-completion.
Tips: you can check other props type by hover to it. Import it and use it like Variants type in this case.
[image: Tips img]

Comment: I dont find any tyepscript examples. I want to use the variants and create the types elsewhere.

Comment: so the problem here is: "how to use framer motion with types" or "how to create framer-motion variants with types" not "i can't install types for framer-motion".

Comment: @Abhijeet I added an example. check it please